# check for changes in form via Ajax

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a little auto-suggest jQuery script. What it does is when I start typing it looks into my database for matches via an Ajax Post. When I click on a result the input field get the value wich I picked.

That works but what I want is to check if the value of the input has changed its value.

What i tried is

```
$("input").change(function(){
   alert('change'); 
});
```

but it doesnt work.

Is there a way to check if a form input field has changed his value from an AJAX POST?

Comment: So after the user selects something from the autocomplete, you want to check if they have typed anything additional into the input?

Comment: When the user select something from the autocomplete I want to check if the input has changed, I want to add a function at the moment the input field has changed.

Answer (score 3):

`.changed` is not a function in jQuery.

Here the function is `.change` use that:

```
$("input").change(function(){ 
    alert('change'); 
});
```

Use the following function instead of above:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ui-autocomplete").click(function(){
     alert("changed the input field.");
});

});
```

I am using the class `ui-autocomplete` as you told that you are using the jQuery autocomplete. You can detect the name of class or id by using the firebug.

Comment: Made a typo, I used change instead of changed

Comment: OP accept that this was fault from his side. on the basis of that this was answer.

Comment: @LeonvanderVeen wait after finding proper answer I will updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Triggering a Change Event

Only a few event types automatically activate a change event. For your particular application you may need to trigger the event manually as described below.

from the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to  elements,  boxes and  elements.
>
> To trigger the event manually, apply .change() without arguments:

```
$('#other').click(function() {
  $('.target').change();
});
```

I wrote a small utility for myself which monitors object states and propagates state changes: [Oculus](https://github.com/victusfate/oculus). It is currently used only in a small client side project, but it's a simple enough pattern to be reusable.